# Returning a sorted Dataframe from a given Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, pivot-table

I need to write a function that takes a dataframe, called theData, a column, called groupBy, and another column, called orderBy, and create another sorted dataframe that represents a pivot table.

It needs to be grouped 'groupBy' and sorted from largest to smallest using the average values of orderBy.

Now, there are some givens that I cannot change...

theData is the datafarme I am interpreting
groupBy is the column to group by
orderBy is the column to sort from largest to smallest, by average.

I have also been given the below format...

```
def createPivot(theData, groupBy, orderBy):
# YOUR CODE HERE
return retDF
```

So far, this is what I have...

```
def createPivot(theData, groupBy, orderBy):
retDF = theData.groupby(groupBy).mean().reset_index().sort_values(by=orderBy, inplace=True)
return retDF
```

I am getting an error from the test code telling me that I am not returning a dataframe. I have also been advised by my professor that I should basically be able to accomplish the task with one line of code. I think I have been massively overthinking it, so a simple answer would be incredibly helpful here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, this is what I have come up with:

```
def createPivot(theData, groupBy, orderBy):
    retDF = theData.groupby(groupBy).mean().sort_values(by=orderBy,ascending=False)
    return retDF
```

Comment: That looks to have done it! Thank you so much!

Comment: great ! Thankyou @Skrrrt_Cobain